In Android Studio what is enableEdgeToEdge() in activity?
I am still using xml for view but when now I create a new activity it auto fills the enableEdgeToEdge. I am not sure what it is and what's the use of it can I remove it will that affect the activity
I did not tried any thing yet.

According to https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/edge-to-edge it allows you to display views behind the status and navigation bar of the device to let them use the entire space from the top edge of the display to the bottom edge.

I added an explanation why it is called edge-to-edge.
