How to stop dark mode from turning text white in Android app
I made a simple Android app based on this Android Basics codelab:
text
Here is my full code:
text
The problem can be recreated by running this code as well:
package com.example.stackoverflowmre

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.example.stackoverflowmre.ui.theme.StackOverflowMRETheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            StackOverflowMRETheme {
                Surface(modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize())
                {
                    Greeting(
                        name = "Android",
                        modifier = Modifier
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(
        text = "Hello $name!",
        // Specifically setting the text color to black
        // doesn't help either
        color = Color.Black,
        modifier = modifier
            .background(Color(0xFFD8F7A7))
            .padding(80.dp)
    )
}

My problem is the following: The app runs as intended when my phone (Android 11, MIUI Global 12.5.5) is in light mode. The text is black, so there is good contrast with the light green background. However, when I switch my phone to dark mode, the text becomes white, and so it is hard to see.
Below are screenshots of my app in light and dark mode, respectively.


I tried changing things in both themes.xml, and theme.kt, as instructed by countless online tutorials (and some stackoverflow answers), but nothing worked.
Having color = Color.Black in the Text composables also doesn't help.
What am I missing here? Can I not just disable dark mode in the app somehow?

According to the documentation of the Surface composable, the Surface will use the contentColor to specify a preferred color for the content. If no contentColor is set, then the Surface will try and match its backgroundColor to a color defined in the theme colorScheme, and return the corresponding contentColor.
Remove the Surface composable and the color of your text will not change with respect to the device theme.
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            StackOverflowMRETheme {
                Box(modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize())
                {
                    Greeting(
                        name = "Android",
                        modifier = Modifier
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


When using enableEdgeToEdge you probably should wrap the content in a Scaffold and apply the padding provided to its content lambda. Also see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78823208/scaffold-vs-surface
